# How do I set a shadow color for Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Sorry, I can hardly speak English.

machine translation:

How do I set a shadow color for Jetpack Compose?

I can set shadows, but they're ugly.

Jetpack Compose code:

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.width(160.dp).height(56.dp),
    shape = CircleShape,
    elevation = 2.dp,
) {
    ...
}
```

I want to create a shadow in the code below.

SwiftUI code:

```
ZStack {
    ...
}
.shadow(color: Color("button_shadow"), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
.shadow(color: Color("button_shadow"), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 4)
```

Dark mode also requires a white shadow.

[image]

[image]

You want to be able to customize the color of the shadow.

Comment: There is a deleted answer with a relevant and useful gist here: https://gist.github.com/cedrickring/0497965b0658d6727aaec531f59e8c5c

Answer (score 14):

Compose 1.2.0-alpha06 now supports shadow color attribute for the graphics layer modifier! `ambientColor` and `spotColor` can change the color of your shadow.
It's only useful with shapes though (`CircleShape`, `RectangleShape`, `RoundedCornerShape`, or your custom shape)

```
fun Modifier.shadow(
    elevation: Dp,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    clip: Boolean = false,
    elevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    ambientColor: Color = DefaultShadowColor,
    spotColor: Color = DefaultShadowColor,
)
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-alpha06

Comment: It doesn't work on lower APIs :( Check the comment in GraphicsLayerScope:


Note that this parameter is only supported on Android 9 (Pie) and above. On older versions, this property always returns Color.Black and setting new values is ignored

Answer (score 10):

In my case for cycle I use this workaround:

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(64.dp)
            .background(
                brush = Brush.radialGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        Color.Yellow,
                        Color.Transparent
                    )
                )
            )
            .padding(bottom = 4.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Surface(
            shape = CircleShape,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(55.dp)
                .background(Color.Transparent)
                .clickable { }
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding()
                    .background(Color.Gray),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(35.dp),
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Refresh,
                    contentDescription = "",
                    tint =  Color.Yellow
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

there is the preview:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but what if the composable isn't circle? With square/rounded views it won't work

Comment: Compose 1.2.0 is stable now, you need use their api Modifier.shadow()

Answer (score 5):

Well, this has recently changed and you can do it using **Material 3 Jetpack Compose library.** Just call shadow on modifier and set desired color.

Add dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha12'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:1.2.0-beta02"
```

and add shadow modifier.

```
 .shadow(
         elevation = 8.dp,
         ambientColor = primaryBlue,
         spotColor = primaryBlue
        )
```

sample code.

```
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_capture_icon),
        contentDescription = "capture",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .background(shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp), color = primaryBlue)
            .size(60.dp)
            .shadow(
                elevation = 8.dp,
                ambientColor = primaryBlue,
                spotColor = primaryBlue
            )
            .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
            .padding(12.dp)
            .clickable {
                context.startActivity(Intent(context, GeoSpatialActivity::class.java))
            },
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = Color.White)
    )
```

Comment: You don't really need material3 dependency as it's in compose ui 1.2.0-alpha06.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code below to add a colorful shadow to your `Modifier`:

```
    fun Modifier.advanceShadow(
    color: Color = Color.Black,
    borderRadius: Dp = 16.dp,
    blurRadius: Dp = 16.dp,
    offsetY: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetX: Dp = 0.dp,
    spread: Float = 1f,
) = drawBehind {
    this.drawIntoCanvas {
        val paint = Paint()
        val frameworkPaint = paint.asFrameworkPaint()
        val spreadPixel = spread.dp.toPx()
        val leftPixel = (0f - spreadPixel) + offsetX.toPx()
        val topPixel = (0f - spreadPixel) + offsetY.toPx()
        val rightPixel = (this.size.width)
        val bottomPixel = (this.size.height + spreadPixel)

        if (blurRadius != 0.dp) {
            /*
                The feature maskFilter used below to apply the blur effect only works
                with hardware acceleration disabled.
             */
            frameworkPaint.maskFilter =
                (BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius.toPx(), BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL))
        }

        frameworkPaint.color = color.toArgb()
        it.drawRoundRect(
            left = leftPixel,
            top = topPixel,
            right = rightPixel,
            bottom = bottomPixel,
            radiusX = borderRadius.toPx(),
            radiusY = borderRadius.toPx(),
            paint
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible at the moment but you can star the issue here: [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/160665122)

The idea would be to have a modifier for the color, opacity, shape etc.

Comment: Machine translation：

Thank you very much. Thank you. I have a feeling that they may be very persistent about Material Design.

原文：

非常感谢谢谢，我感觉他们可能是对  Material Design 非常执着。

Comment: How about workaround solution utilising Jetpack Compose Canvas for example?

Answer (score 0):

the link in the comment of @EpicPandaForce uses converts color to int using android.graphics.Color.Argb(Long) which required Api Level >= 26. I found another link in that gist comment in which function argb is used and it is in API level 1 added.

https://gist.github.com/arthurgonzaga/598267f570e38425fc52f97b30e0619d